# How to retrieve list of keys based on condition on value from struct array in swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, struct

How do I get the array containing names for employees for whom present is true in following code? I'm looking for simple one line solution using map or filter.

```
struct Employee {
    var name: String?
    var present: Bool?
}

var employeeList = [Employee]()

employeeList.append(Employee(name: "A", present:true))
employeeList.append(Employee(name: "B", present:false))
employeeList.append(Employee(name: "C", present:false))
employeeList.append(Employee(name: "D", present:true))

// Get the list of employees who have present == true
// Should return ["A", "D"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
let res = employeeList.compactMap { $0.present ? $0.name : nil }
```

Remove `?` for `struct` properties if you always supply the value